# Read excel and populate 2 dimensional array in typescript

Tags: arrays, excel, typescript, multidimensional-array

i would like to read a simple table in an excel sheet (x rows, y cols) and populate a 2 dimensional array in typescript. Something like below:

client_id   orderid 
1 :          12 3 45 78 97 
2 :          67 89 12 
3 :          7 90 23

Do you know a good excel library ? Thank you

regards,
Titi

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the table name and then you can use `getRange().getValues()` to capture the values within the table as a 2 day array. Example:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 const theTableName:string = "table1"; // or whatever the name is
 var theTable = workbook.getTable(theTableName);
 var allValues = theTable.getRange().getValues();
 // allVallues is now an 2-day array with values
}
```